# Dynamically round number to n decimal places depending on magnitude

Tags: javascript

I need a function which takes a calculated value (can range from very small to very large) and rounds it to a number of decimal places for display. The number of decimal places should depend on the magnitude of the input and so I can't just use something like `.toFixed(n)` because `n` is unknown.

I came up with the following, but have the feeling there's a much better way of doing this:

```
function format_output(output) {
    if (output > 10000) {
        output = output.toFixed(0);
} else {
        if (output > 100 && output < 10000) {
        output = output.toFixed(1);
    } else {
            if (output>1 && output <100) {
                output = output.toFixed(3);
    } else {
        // repeat as necessary
    }
return output;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement you should look into scientific notation

```
output.toExponential();
```

If you dont want to use scientific notation try this instead:

```
function format_output(output) {
    var n =  Math.log(output) / Math.LN10;
    var x = 4-n;
    if(x<0)
        x=0;
    output = output.toFixed(x);
    return output;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't sound as though it would help at all for the sort of requirement the user if presenting, presumably presenting data with a reasonable degree of precision.

Comment: Thanks, but the output is intended for "non-technical" people - I'm looking for something that will display numbers like 0.0023, 1.63, 100.4 and 10,000

Comment: in that case can you not take log of the number and then use that  with .toFixed

Comment: I added the other solution

Comment: Just watch the boundary conditions.  This throws an exception when passed 0.

Comment: Oh yes true also if it is negative, make it positive before passing it to the log function

Answer (score 6):

It does seem that you want to limit this to about five places of precision.  This might do so more explicitly:

```
var toPrecision = function(precision) {
    return function(nbr) {
        if (typeof nbr !== 'number') return 0; //???
        if (nbr === 0) return 0;
        var abs = Math.abs(nbr);
        var sign = nbr / abs;
        nbr = abs;
        var digits = Math.ceil(Math.log(nbr)/Math.LN10);
        var factor = Math.pow(10, precision - digits);
        var result = nbr * factor;
        result = Math.round(result, 0);
        return result / factor;
    };
};

var format_output = toPrecision(5);

format_output(1234567.89012); // 1234600
format_output(987.654321); // 987.65
format_output(-.00246813579); // -0.0024681
```

Of course you can combine those into a two-argument function if you prefer:

```
var toPrecision = function(nbr, precision) {
    if (typeof nbr !== 'number') return 0; //???
    if (nbr === 0) return 0;
    var abs = Math.abs(nbr);
    var sign = nbr / abs;
    nbr = abs;
    var digits = Math.ceil(Math.log(nbr)/Math.LN10);
    var factor = Math.pow(10, precision - digits);
    var result = nbr * factor;
    result = Math.round(result, 0);
    return result / factor;
};

toPrecision(1234567.89012, 5); // 1234600
```

Or, if that floats your boat, you could attach it to the Math object:

```
Math.toPrecision = function(nbr, precision) {
    // ...
}
```

### Update (May, 2020)

Many years later, with the ubiquity of ES6, I would write this differently.  It might look something like this:

```
var toPrecision = (precision) => (nbr, _, __, powerOf10) => 
  nbr === 0
    ? 0
    : (
        powerOf10 = 10 ** (precision - Math .ceil (Math .log10 (Math .abs (nbr)))), 
        Math .round (nbr * powerOf10) / powerOf10
      )
```

Comment: Your last solution is really great! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to limit the value to 5 significant digits. The following does it for a limited range of values (99999 to 0.00001), you can work out how to do it for the rest. Note that there may be rounding errors in some old browsers for some values.

```
  <input onchange="
    var bits = this.value.split('.');
    var places = 5 - bits[0].length;

    if (places < 0) {
      places = 0;

    } else if (bits[0] == 0) {
      places = 5;
    }
    this.value = Number(this.value).toFixed(places); 
  ">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a method I came up with when trying to solve the same problem, how to dynamically round in order to present both very large and very small numbers to the end user.

```
function get_exponent_value(num){
     value = num.toExponential();
     string_e_value = value.split('e')[1];
     return parseInt(string_e_value);
}
```

This gives you the exponent value of a given number. Then, to use it, you round based on this number:

```
 var EValue = get_exponent_value(val);
 if (EValue <= -1)
       val = float_to_fixed(val, ((EValue * -1) + 3));
 else
       val = float_to_fixed(val);
```

This way it gives you reasonable-looking small numbers, and trims decimals from large numbers. It isn't perfect but it works well for now until I can think of / find a better solution.